# Smooth Scrolling in SDL

Tags: google-chrome, 2d, sdl, sdl-2

My use case is need to build large table using SDL. and I’m looking for smooth scroll like browser does. Anyone have idea ? how to implement smooth scrolling in SDL ?. I tried with SDL_MouseWheel event . but it doesn’t look smooth.

Comment: You mean performing scrolling animation over some time when single mouse wheel event is received (i.e. when I move wheel by one click actual scrolling starts immediately but completes a second later)? Well, interpolate scrolled position based on remaining time util animation completion.

Answer (score 0):

If the target devices have an "analogue-y" input method, like a touchscreen or trackpad, you will find the smoothest subjective scrolling experience by using that. Perhaps `SDL_TouchFingerEvent` or `SDL_MultiGestureEvent` will get you what you need.

If all you have to work with is a traditional notched scroll wheel, you'll need to interpolate, as @keltar suggests.

The absolute easiest way to accomplish that is linear over time, something like

```cpp
/* on mouse wheel event received */
if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEWHEEL)
{
  targetScrollPosition += event.wheel.y * MY_SCROLL_SENSITIVITY;
}

/* each frame, animate scroll */
if (visibleScrollPosition < targetScrollPosition)
{
  visibleScrollPosition += MY_SCROLL_SPEED;
} 
else if (visibleScrollPosition > targetScrollPosition)
{
  visibleScrollPosition -= MY_SCROLL_SPEED;
}
```

However you'll find this is not much smoother and quite unfriendly to rapid scrolling, so you'll want to look into cubic or other methods.

Here is some background reading with code examples. http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/

Bear in mind that the user can scroll further--in either direction--during the animation so it needs to follow the desired position at all times. There is nothing more frustrating than scrolling down, then scrolling up, and *then* watching the viewport slowly do both instead of just going straight to where I wanted to be. In fact, I *personally* don't like smooth scrolling at all, and usually turn it off in favor of immediate feedback; so, if this table will have users other than yourself, before putting in a ton of effort be sure to account for their personal taste.